# Fail to Jump from PDF line to source code in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I am trying to jump from line in pdf to the source code but it does not work.
From source code to the pdf has an error of 'File not found'.
I have already written pdflatex -synctex=1 in the configure Texmaker but it still does not work.

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your issue better. Can you show your configuration for TeXmaker?

Comment: Honestly the phrase "does not work" should be banned from this site. Please explain exactly what you actually did and what happens (or does not happen) when you do. Does the `.synctex.gz` exist in the same folder as the file?